# ActionBar logo not showing

Tags: android-actionbar, android-appcompat

i have declared the logo in the manifest file like this :

```
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
```

and the custom theme is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

but the logo is not showing in the actionbar, i have tried many ways but not working, can anybody pls help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new appcompat 21, the pattern is changed.

The Action Bar follows the material design guidelines and uses a Toolbar.
As you can read [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html):

```
The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is 
    discouraged on API 21 devices and newer.
```

If you would like an application icon, you can use the method `setLogo()`.

You should read this [official post](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).